# I want to carry on using hangouts for sms

Tags: sms, google-hangouts

I assume i can install an older apk before the sms integration timer was added, freeze updates and use hangouts for SMS forever.

I have two questions

1) how can i find the most recent version that won't have the warning message
2) where are my SMS stored, will i lose the history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this all good. I went through apkmirror and kept updating versions of hangouts until I found one that didn't throw the "SMS will not work in hangouts soon".

I stopped on version 16, but could possibly have gone one higher I think. I'm not too bothered about having the latest features for hangouts, it's just a text messenger.

I then disabled updates in play store and I'm good to go.

Thanks for the answers everyone

Answer (score 1):

You can check previous versions at [this link](https://www.apkmirror.com/). You SMS are stored on your device locally. You can always change to another SMS application like [Textra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra)
or [Default Android Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging)

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of apkmirror, I should've mentioned that in the question. I was more accurately asking if anyone knew which version, or a way of me finding out which version, I could install that wouldn't keep telling me that SMS will stop working soon. I'm currently working my way up through versions until I get that error message!

Comment: Yeah got it. But if they have any server side lock then it will not possible I think. Your messages are stored locally. You can switch over another messaging application if you wish. :)